# AfterScenario selenium Java did not work (API)

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have tried to add this tag @AfterScenario, my purpose here is after each scenario done, i want to get the test result(passed of fail) but this tags did not work for me

```
import net.serenitybdd.core.annotations.events.AfterScenario;

public class reportTest {

    @AfterScenario
    public void afterScenario(){
        System.out.println("hahahahhaha");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe try using junit or testng for this hooks. Try changing the import and annotation.

junit :

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass
@BeforeClass
(your code)
```

testng :

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
@BeforeClass
(your code)
```

If you're using Cucumber and POM, import these from io.cucumber